# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to get a value from the user and then update the start time and end time for biding in the table. But i am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message Table 'fyp.biding' doesn't exist' in
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\profile\user\sadd_property_bidding.php:61 Stack trace: #0
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\profile\user\sadd_property_bidding.php(61): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'UPDATE biding S...') #1 {main} thrown in
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\profile\user\sadd_property_bidding.php on line 61

```
//Change the 25 to  however many minutes you want to countdown
$targetDate = strtotime('+3 days');
$actualDate = time();
echo $targetDate;
echo $actualDate;
$sql2 = "UPDATE biding SET start='$actualDate', end='$targetDate' WHERE      
id='$id'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: seems that your error is related to a non-existing table, can you post the relevant part of the mysql connection in your code, and also the database/table in your mysql installation?

Comment: Can you post your conneciton info? (remove the password) As i can see it tries to connect to the fyp Database. It that the name of the database your table is in? If not you can try to specify the database as well like so: `UPDATE tablename.biding SET...`

Comment: <?php
     $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','fyp') or die("Database Error");
     ?>

Comment: DB table structure :

Comment: `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  
  `start` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `end` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message Table 'fyp.biding' doesn't exist' in

This is as clear an error message as you'll ever get. The table `biding` doesn't exists. It may be a typo in the name or your haven't created it.